# How can I sync my Outlook calendar with my Android phone calendar?

Tags: sync, calendar, outlook

I have Galaxy Europa GT-I5500 Android phone with me.  The problem I am facing is I am able to Sync my Contacts and Notes with my Outlook 2007, but I am not able to sync my my phone calendar with Outlook 2007.

I'd appreciate if anyone can help me with the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find [MyPhoneExplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client) quite useful. It does not only sync your contacts etc. with outlook, but provides a lot of additional useful features, such as managing your SMS, Calllists, Apps, Files, handling Calls, create backups...

You might want to visit the [products page](http://www.fjsoft.at/en/highlight.php) for more detailled information.

Comment: No love for us Linux+Thunderbird users - Windows only :(

Comment: Logos, are you kidding? You don't want to tell me you use Outlook on Linux, do you? That's what the OP asked for (Outlook), hence this answer. Not that I use any MS software (MS-free zone here :) Ask a question about Linux, and I tell you that Thunderbird, Evolution, KOffice etc. can directly access the Google calendar -- hence no need for additional "helpers" on this ground, unless you don't sync with Google. And even then, plenty of possibilities ;)

Comment: No, I don't use OL on Linux - hence adding the "+TB" to my comment.  It was just a comment, not an answer.  Hence the comment :)  It looks like a spiffy app though, hence my sadness that it's Windows only.

Comment: ack. Reminds me of the Palm Desktop, from the screenshots. Yeah, bad luck for us with things like that. Those folks still didn't check they could get new customers here... I wouldn't even mind paying a reasonable 1-time-fee for good stuff ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is this a local Outlook calendar?  If so, you might want to migrate your appointments to your Google account's calendar, then add your Google calendar to Outlook (pretty simple to do).  That way it will sync automatically, as well as being available on the web.